# Angular 2 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: 'app-main' is not a known element:

Tags: angular, angular2-template, typescript2.0, angular2-modules

I have two separate modules `app.module.ts` and `core.module.ts` for loading two selectors `app` and `app-main`.

The folder structure is like below:

```
|main.ts
|-App
|  |-app.module.ts
|  |-Components
|    |-app.component.ts
|
|-Core
|  |-core.module.ts
|  |-Components
|    |-core.component.ts
```

**main.ts**

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { AppModule } from './App/app.module';
if (process.env.ENV === 'production') {
    enableProdMode();
}
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CoreModule } from '../Core/core.module';
import { AppComponent } from './Components/app.component';
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        CoreModule
    ],
    declarations: [ AppComponent ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `<app-main></app-main>`
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

**core.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CoreComponent } from './Components/core.component';
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ],
    declarations: [ CoreComponent ]
})
export class CoreModule {}
```

**core.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-main',
    template: ` App Loaded From Core`
})
export class CoreComponent {}
```

**I am getting the issue of `'app-main' is not a known element:` as in below image:**
[image: app-main is not a known element]
When i change the selector to `app-main` it works but there is no any errors and output. Just a blank page is returned.

**How could i render the template of different module in the `app.component.ts` using the selector? Or load different templates from different modules in a single template?**

Comment: Did you forget about exports?

Comment: @yurzui yeah just forgot about that. Thanks for the reminder. +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to list the components in `exports` that should be available in importing modules:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ],
    declarations: [ CoreComponent ],
    exports: [ CoreComponent ] // <<<< added
})
export class CoreModule {}
```